# How do i map through a data and increment its corresponding data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to keep track a vote on each time it's submitted. All corresponding data in the submittedVoteId is what I want to use to count the vote for the aspirants

Here are the data I got when voters submitted their votes

```
const votes = [
  {
   id: 1,
   Name: "john"
   AdmissionNo: "3030"
   SubmittedVoteId: {
                farmer: "10117"
                teacher: "60254"
                doctor: "25254"
                }
   },
   {
   id: 2,
   Name: "emmy"
   AdmissionNo: "2222"
   SubmittedVoteId: {
                farmer: "10117"
                teacher: "60254"
                doctor: "42365"
                }
   },
   {
   id: 3,
   Name: "ruth"
   AdmissionNo: "5050"
   SubmittedVoteId: {
                farmer: "48254"
                teacher: "60254"
                doctor: "25254"
                }
   }
]
```

*NOTE*  the submittedVotedId is who a voter voted for.

I want to increment each aspirants/votee that have same submittedVoteId by 1

I don't know how to go about it from here

Comment: can you explain that using an example?

Comment: @yushan let's say I have people contesting for different position each candidate belongs to a party, the parties have their own unique ID. Whenever a voter submit his/her votes I receive the ID based on who the voter voted for

Comment: **I want to increment each aspirants/votee that have same submittedVoteId by 1** can you extend that example to explain this requirement?

Comment: What does "aspirants/votee" mean? I see no such keys or properties in your example snippet. Can you please clarify what you mean and want incremented? Other than `id` I see no number values that can be incremented. An example expected output would be really helpful. Also, what have you tried already on your own? Have you a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to share with us? Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service, please show us some effort on your part.

Comment: The people contesting for a position, I want to count for them based on the number of times their unique ID appears. The submittedVoteId is the reference to a person contesting. I want their votes to be counted +1 till the end of the data.  I hope this explains better. Thank you  @Yushan

Comment: Are you wanting a result like `{ farmer: [{ "10117": 2 }, { "48254": 1 }], teacher: [....`?

Comment: @Drew Reese yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reduce your votes array into an object of submitted vote id key-value pairs where the value is an object of the vote id and vote counts.

```
votes.reduce((votes, { SubmittedVoteId }) => {
  Object.entries(SubmittedVoteId).forEach(([key, id]) => {
    if (!votes[key]) votes[key] = {};
    if (!votes[key][id]) votes[key][id] = 0;
    votes[key][id]++;
  });
  return votes;
}, {});
```

```js
const votes = [
  {
    id: 1,
    Name: "john",
    AdmissionNo: "3030",
    SubmittedVoteId: {
      farmer: "10117",
      teacher: "60254",
      doctor: "25254"
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    Name: "emmy",
    AdmissionNo: "2222",
    SubmittedVoteId: {
      farmer: "10117",
      teacher: "60254",
      doctor: "42365"
    }
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    Name: "ruth",
    AdmissionNo: "5050",
    SubmittedVoteId: {
      farmer: "48254",
      teacher: "60254",
      doctor: "25254"
    }
  }
];

const res = votes.reduce((votes, { SubmittedVoteId }) => {
  Object.entries(SubmittedVoteId).forEach(([key, id]) => {
    if (!votes[key]) votes[key] = {};
    if (!votes[key][id]) votes[key][id] = 0;
    votes[key][id]++;
  });
  return votes;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: This is really helpful. i was able to use it to solve other problem. Thank you